# OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long in python though date are defined as datetime64[ns] type object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

[image]

[image]

Getting overflow error while setting the frequency

```py
df_train.index.freq = 'W'.
```

Error:

> ```sh
> OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-37-bbb3114abe9d> in <module>
> ----> 1 df_train.index.freq = 'W'
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/extension.py in fset(self, value)
>      64 
>      65             def fset(self, value):
> ---> 66                 setattr(self._data, name, value)
>      67 
>      68             fget.__name__ = name
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in freq(self, value)
>     978         if value is not None:
>     979             value = frequencies.to_offset(value)
> --> 980             self._validate_frequency(self, value)
>     981 
>     982         self._freq = value
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py in _validate_frequency(cls, index, freq, **kwargs)
>    1039         try:
>    1040             on_freq = cls._generate_range(
> -> 1041                 start=index[0], end=None, periods=len(index), freq=freq, **kwargs
>    1042             )
>    1043             if not np.array_equal(index.asi8, on_freq.asi8):
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py in _generate_range(cls, start, end, periods, freq, tz, normalize, ambiguous, nonexistent, closed)
>     406                     end = end.tz_localize(None)
>     407             # TODO: consider re-implementing _cached_range; GH#17914
> --> 408             values, _tz = generate_regular_range(start, end, periods, freq)
>     409             index = cls._simple_new(values, freq=freq, dtype=tz_to_dtype(_tz))
>     410 
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/_ranges.py in generate_regular_range(start, end, periods, freq)
>      79         xdr = generate_range(start=start, end=end, periods=periods, offset=freq)
>      80 
> ---> 81         values = np.array([x.value for x in xdr], dtype=np.int64)
>      82 
>      83     return values, tz
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/_ranges.py in <listcomp>(.0)
>      79         xdr = generate_range(start=start, end=end, periods=periods, offset=freq)
>      80 
> ---> 81         values = np.array([x.value for x in xdr], dtype=np.int64)
>      82 
>      83     return values, tz
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/offsets.py in generate_range(start, end, periods, offset)
>    2765 
>    2766     if end is None:
> -> 2767         end = start + (periods - 1) * offset
>    2768 
>    2769     if start is None:
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in >pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.BaseOffset.__radd__()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx in >pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets._BaseOffset.__add__()
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/offsets.py in wrapper(self, other)
>     109                 other = other.tz_localize(None)
>     110 
> --> 111             result = func(self, other)
>     112 
>     113             if self._adjust_dst:
>
> /opt/omniai/software/Miniconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/tseries/offsets.py in apply(self, other)
>    1577                 k -= 1
>    1578 
> -> 1579         return other + timedelta(weeks=k)
>    1580 
>    1581     @apply_index_wraps
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/c_timestamp.pyx in >pandas._libs.tslibs.c_timestamp._Timestamp.__add__()
>
> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try reindexing your dataframe with the appropriate number of periods

```py
df = df.set_index(pd.date_range('2010-02-05', periods=100, freq='W'))
```

Comment: I have data of 421570  rows. If i give periods as 421570 getting  "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" for above step aswell. Is it because of the huge data?

Comment: Than I guess your problem is that your frequency isn't 'W' as 421570 weeks represent more than 8 thousand years. There must be some duplicates

Comment: You can use df.index.nunique() to know how many different indexes you actually have

Comment: I have more than 100 stores and each store has 2 years of data, after trimming the data, im not getting above error any more.

Comment: Then I guess you don't need to specify freq at all, as your indexes are not unique. freq is useful when you define a pd.date_range which is not your case.